# Authenticator - Failed to verify contact [TypeError: Cannot read property 'isEmpty' of undefined]

Tags: react-native

[WARN] 10:01.904 Authenticator - Failed to verify contact [TypeError: Cannot read property 'isEmpty' of undefined]

[image]

just tried to re-config codes

Comment: I am seeing this as well.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like this is a known issue:
https://github.com/aws-amplify/amplify-js/issues/10711

I was able resolve this by installing the unstable version:

```
yarn add aws-amplify-react-native@unstable
```

Once `aws-amplify-react-native` releases version `7.0.2`, this fix should be permanent.